# Can I view the Dropbox desktop app as a window instead of a taskbar icon?

Tags: windows, dropbox

I am using Dropbox on Windows 10. I know that I can click on the taskbar icon to see file syncing progress. Is there a way I can open the app in a window so I don't have to keep opening the taskbar icon to check up on the progress?

I have searched for an answer, but searching for the term "window" results in a lot of other things related to using Dropbox on the Windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I have Drop Box here on Windows 10.

You can right click or left click once on the Task Bar icon and that opens the Drop Box Window so you can see what is going on. I use this quite frequently.

You can just hover over the icon (not open the Window) to see the sync progress as well.

You can double click on the Task Bar icon and open the Windows Explorer view of the files.  I use this a lot.

Look also through the Drop Box Preferences (down arrow beside your initials) to see things you can control as well.

I trust this helps because you can monitor everything in Drop Box.